# Unable to port phone numbers

Tags: telephony

I have some limited experience in telco, and have done number porting in a business environment before.

I have a fairly large number of DIDs with a local telco provider that we use for inbound faxes.  I am considering outsourcing to one of the various third party fax providers, but have been told that the numbers are not able to be ported.

I was under the impression that any number could be ported elsewhere these days.

Can anyone help me understand what would prevent a DID, or range of DIDs, from being ported?  I don't understand whether this is a technical hurdle or a policy/procedural hurdle.

Thanks!

**edit:**  Sorry, this is in the US, area code 662.  We are not doing any sort of physical relocation, but perhaps that's why we might run into issues porting them from our current local dial tone provider to someone like eFax.

Comment: A common reason a number can't be ported is when the number is restricted to a geographical area and your new provider doesn't have a presence in it.

Comment: For what country? What is the history of the phone numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the leap your in the US the actual regulations are for **local** number portability so if your new provider doesn't have a local presence you may not be able to transfer a number to them.

From the [FCC Website](http://www.fcc.gov/guides/portability-keeping-your-phone-number-when-changing-service-providers)

> **Keeping Your Telephone Number When Changing Service Providers**
>
> Under the Federal Communications Commission's "local number
>   portability" rules, you can switch telephone service providers for
>   wireline, wireless or Voice over Internet Protocol and keep your
>   existing phone number if you remain in the same geographic area. If
>   you are moving from one geographic area to another, however, you may
>   not be able to take your number with you.